# sorting list of strings based on date 20210419

Tags: c#

I have. list of files, names of the files are `log20211904.json` what would be the best way to sort this name based on the date that is included in the name of the file? What I get now from my method substring is 20210419 which is not valid date time. I wonder how to do it effectively and get valid DateTimeOffset from 20210419

I was thinking

```
var orderedFIle = new List<LogFile>();
        
var fileDetail = new LogFile()
{
    FileName = "log20210419",

};
var fileDetailtest = new LogFile()
{
    FileName = "log20210420",

};
var test = fileDetail.FileName.Substring(3, 8);
Console.WriteLine(test);
orderedFIle.Add(fileDetail);
orderedFIle.Add(fileDetailtest);

var  list = orderedFIle.OrderByDescending(f => DateTime.Parse(f.FileName.Substring( 3,8)));
foreach (var VARIABLE in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.FileName);
}
```

But the date is actually without  separators. What would be the best approach

Comment: What is the problem with the code above? I´d expect it to work as inteneded, or dou you have same data where it does not? If so please inculde that data, the expected outcome and what you *actually* get

Comment: Why can't you introduce new property to `LogFile` class called `CreatedDate`? Then sort your list of log files based on this date

Comment: the date I get is 20210419
that si the mistake

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly all you should need to do is use an overload of `DateTime.Parse()` that takes a mask, and then use "yyyyMMdd" as the mask.

Comment: you have to provide **how** parsing should be done by using the [overload that expects the format-provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

Comment: Sorting by string won't work because the Day comes before the Month.

Comment: @jdweng no OP changed that. now it's YYYYMMDD. caught me out too.

Comment: @NicholasHunter : The actual filename is still in first line of posting which contains json.  I suspect what OP is actually getting is yyyyddMM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IComparable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HotelManagement
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] filenames = {
                                     "log20211904.json",
                                     "log20211804.json",
                                     "log20211904.json",
                                     "log20210903.json",
                                     "log20211902.json",
                                     "log20211910.json",
                                     "log20211909.json"
                                 };

            string[] results = filenames.OrderBy(x => new SortFileName(x)).ToArray();

 
        }
    }
    public class SortFileName : IComparable<SortFileName>
    {
        private DateTime date { get; set; } 

        public SortFileName(string filename)
        {
            date = DateTime.ParseExact(filename.Substring(3,8), "yyyyddMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        public int CompareTo(SortFileName other)
        {
            return this.date.CompareTo(other.date);

        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Loving the namespace ;)

Comment: @tymtam : It was from another posting.

Answer (score 1):

Since the date in the string is already in a sortable format you can just sort by the full log name.

For example:

```
var l = new List<LogFile>();
l.Add(new LogFile(){FileName = "log20210419"});
l.Add(new LogFile(){FileName = "log20210420"});
l.Add(new LogFile(){FileName = "log20210101"});
foreach (var f in l.OrderByDescending(f => f.FileName))
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.FileName);
}
```

prints

```
log20210420
log20210419
log20210101
```

If you really want to parse then you can use `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(f.FileName, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a class as follows.

```
/// <summary>
/// Use a regular expression to validate the file name and extract the date parts.
/// Implement IComparable to define a default sort order.
/// </summary>
public class JsonLogFileName : IComparable<JsonLogFileName>
{
    // Private data members.
    private string fileName;
    private DateTime fileDate;

    // Public accessor methods.
    public String FileName => this.fileName;

    public DateTime FileDate => this.fileDate;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    public JsonLogFileName(string fileName) {

        // Use a regular expression to validate the file name
        // and extract the date parts.
        Match m = Regex.Match(fileName, @"^log(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).json$");
        if (!m.Success) {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        this.fileName = fileName;

        int year = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
        int month = int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value);
        int day = int.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value);

        this.fileDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }

    // Default sort order
    public int CompareTo(JsonLogFileName other) {
        return DateTime.Compare(this.FileDate, other.FileDate);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this.

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {

    List<JsonLogFileName> jsonLogFileNameList = new List<JsonLogFileName> {
        new JsonLogFileName("log20210419.json"),
        new JsonLogFileName("log20210418.json"),
        new JsonLogFileName("log20210417.json"),
        new JsonLogFileName("log20210416.json"),
        new JsonLogFileName("log20210415.json"),
    };

    jsonLogFileNameList.Sort();

    foreach (JsonLogFileName jsonFileName in jsonLogFileNameList) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{jsonFileName.FileName}: {jsonFileName.FileDate}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```